# How do I get a polyline Displayed in Mapbox Visual for Power BI?

Tags: mapbox, power-bi

All of the Mapbox Examples involve point layers where you add a csv and drop lat/lngs into power bi.  I have also tried creating a custom map in studio and adding and styling my polyline.  However when I load the custom map in power bi it shows the correct basemap but my polyline is not there. Are there extra steps in enabling this layer in my custom map?

Comment: Did you publish the style first?

Comment: Yes sir! @AndrewHarvey.